# $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$, differentiable, not constant with $f(a) = f(b)$ has points s.t. $f(x) = f(y)$ and $f'(x) \neq f'(y)$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Is this statement true?

Let $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a non constant differentiable such that $f(a) = f(b)$, then there are numbers $x,y \in [a,b]$ such that $f(x) = f(y)$, but $f'(x) \neq f'(y)$.

If yes, could someone give me a hint on how to prove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $f(t)>f(a)$ for some $t\in [a,b]$.
Then $f$ attains its global maximum at some $c\in(a,b)$.
Let $d=\max(f^{-1}(f(a))\cap [a,c])$ be the greatest number below $c$ where the function has the same value as at $a$ (and $b$). Then by the MVT, for some $x\in(d,c)$, we have $f'(x)=\frac{f(c)-f(a)}{c-d}>0$ and by choice of $d$,  we have $f(a)<f(x)<f(c)$.
By the IVT, the set $Y=f^{-1}(f(x))\cap[c,b]$ is non-empty and closed.
Let $y=\min Y$. Then $f(y)=f(x)$ and $f'(y)\le 0< f'(x)$.

A symmetric argument applies if $f(t)<f(a)$ for some $t\in[a,b]$.

Comment: Nothing in OP's question says that $f'$ is continuous, so unless you assume it you should not use the MVT like that.

Comment: @SergeBallesta Differentiability implies continuity.

Comment: But not of the derivative...

Comment: Still, your answer does not use continuity of $f'$ anywhere. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

there are points on a curve symmetric with respect to y axis, with equal values while going uphill and while going downhill.

Comment: Yes I realized this, but stil couldn't find a point with positive derivative at one side and negative on the other